# Alguém consegue identificar o erro nesse código?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Dias atrás fiz uma pergunta sobre [como adicionar classe a um elemeto ao clicar no botão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3945/como-adicionar-classe-ao-pr%c3%b3ximo-elemento-ao-clicar-no-bot%c3%a3o), as respostas foram satisfatórias (fiz usando JQuery como me sugeriram), porém resolvi criar uma função usando apenas javascript puro (a fins de estudo), só que ocorreu um bug no meio do caminho e não consegui solucionar, será que alguém consegue encontrar o bug nesse código?

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('Contar');
function AddClass(id){
    //pega o valor do botao
    var tipo = document.getElementById(id).value;
    //pegar o item da lista
    var iten = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    //cria uma sessão para gravar os valores dos cliques
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        if(sessionStorage.Contar){
            if(tipo == 'proximo'){
                sessionStorage.Contar=Number(sessionStorage.Contar)+1;
                if(sessionStorage.Contar == iten.length){
                    sessionStorage.Contar=5;
                }
            }else 
            if(tipo == 'anterior'){
                sessionStorage.Contar=Number(sessionStorage.Contar)-1;
                if(sessionStorage.Contar == 0){
                    sessionStorage.Contar=0;
                }
            }
        }else{
            sessionStorage.Contar=0;
        }
    }
    //resgata o valor da sessão
    var valor = sessionStorage.Contar
    if(tipo == 'proximo'){
        if(valor > 0){
            //remove a classe do item anterior
            iten.item(valor-1).removeAttribute('class');
        }
    }else 
    if(tipo == 'anterior'){
        if(valor < 5){
            //remove a classe do item anterior
            iten.item(valor+1).removeAttribute('class');
        }
    }
    //adiciona classe ao próximo item
    iten.item(valor).setAttribute('class', 'selected');
    }
```

**Meu html é esse:**

```
    <button onClick="AddClass('anterior');" id="anterior" value='anterior'>anterior</button>
<button onClick="AddClass('proximo');" id="proximo" value='proximo'>proximo</button>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
```

Não postei no JSFidle porque na minha máquina o site está ficando todo bugado como podem ver aqui:

[image]

Comment: Da algum erro no console?

Comment: Sim, quando clico no botão "anterior", dá esse erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeAttribute' of null

Comment: Então é porque você está tentando chamar esse método em um objecto que não foi inicializado. Talvez você tenha que usar colchetes ao invés de parênteses? Acho que item é um vetor e não um método, certo?

Comment: Hum cara, eu não tenho um conhecimento muito aprofundado de Javascript, comecei a estudar faz pouco tempo

Comment: Não, itens é acessado com parênteses mesmo. Só que o `if(sessionStorage.Contar == 0)` deveria ser `sessionStorage.Contar == -1`, não?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Além do erro do contador, está acontecendo que quando você recupera o "contador" na linha `var valor = sessionStorage.Contar` ele acaba retornando o número como texto, então quando você tenta fazer `valor+1` ele faz `"1" + 1` e isso da `"11"` e na sua lista não existe `item("11")` por isso o `null`.

Utilizei o `parseInt` para resolver isso. Segue o código com as alterações do contador também.

```
function AddClass(id) {
    //pega o valor do botao
    var tipo = document.getElementById(id).value;
    //pegar o item da lista
    var iten = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    //cria uma sessão para gravar os valores dos cliques
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        if(sessionStorage.Contar){
            if(tipo == 'proximo'){
                sessionStorage.Contar=Number(sessionStorage.Contar)+1;
                if(sessionStorage.Contar == iten.length){
                    sessionStorage.Contar = iten.length - 1;
                }
            }else 
            if(tipo == 'anterior'){
                sessionStorage.Contar=Number(sessionStorage.Contar)-1;
                if(sessionStorage.Contar < 0){
                    sessionStorage.Contar=0;
                }
            }
        }else{
            sessionStorage.Contar=0;
        }
    }
    //resgata o valor da sessão
    var valor = parseInt(sessionStorage.Contar);
    if(tipo == 'proximo'){
        if(valor > 0){
            //remove a classe do item anterior
            iten.item(valor-1).removeAttribute('class');
        }
    }else 
    if(tipo == 'anterior'){
        if(valor < iten.length){
            //remove a classe do item anterior
            iten.item(valor+1).removeAttribute('class');
        }
    }
    //adiciona classe ao próximo item
    iten.item(valor).setAttribute('class', 'selected');
}
```

Fiz uma alteração na hora de contar mais também, substitui o `5` por `iten.length - 1`

Comment: Valeu mesmo cara! Deu certo agora, sei que são erros bobos, mas comecei estudar javascript faz pouco tempo XD

Comment: Errando que a gente aprende heuaheuahea, o JavaScript possui tipagem fraca então você vai ver direto esses tipos de problema na hora de trabalhar com números e textos.

Answer (score 5):

O erro está nessa parte:

```
if(tipo == 'anterior'){
  sessionStorage.Contar=Number(sessionStorage.Contar)-1;
  if(sessionStorage.Contar == 0){
    sessionStorage.Contar=0;
  }
}
```

o `if` deveria ser igual a -1 e não a 0. o correto seria:

```
if(tipo == 'anterior'){
  sessionStorage.Contar=Number(sessionStorage.Contar)-1;
  if(sessionStorage.Contar == -1){
    sessionStorage.Contar = 0;
  }
}
```

O que acontece é que quando o Contar é subtraído 1, `0-1 = -1` e não 0, como a sua lógica propunha. Isso foi o que eu vi, só olhando o código por cima.

Comment: Entendi, alterei aqui mas continuou dando erro: acho q o erro está nessa parte também: if(tipo == 'anterior'){
  if(sessionStorage.Contar < 5){
   //remove a classe do item anterior
   iten.item(valor+1).removeAttribute('class');
  }
 } dei um alert para testar e vi que o valor não está somando, pelo contrário, está apenas concatenando

Comment: Antes do `removeAttribute`, coloca essa linha: `console.log(iten.item(valor+1));` e vê se ele não está colocando `null` no console

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Avelar No final, estava colocando como null mesmo, mas conforme foi sugerido, eu coloquei o parseInt(sessionStorage.Contar) e deu certo XD. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!